# Cannot display Unicode characters in Ionic/ Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I have created an api in php which returns unicode data.

```
 echo(json_encode($ary, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

it returns just `?????` but in android it displays data correctly after receiving. 
But Ionic does not display it.
What might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use $sce (Strict Contextual Escaping), see the sample below

```js
var mOverview = angular.module('mOverview', []);

mOverview.controller('mOverviewController', function ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.mData = [
    {
        'name': '&darr; '+'NASDAQ', // here the unicode is &darr; but the output is also &darr; which is supposed to be a down-arrow
        'amount': '15,698.85',
        'upDown': '+105.84'
        }
    ];
});

mOverview.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mOverview">
  <div ng-controller="mOverviewController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="md in mData">
        <td ng-bind-html="md.name | unsafe"></td>
        <td>{{md.amount}}</td>
        <td>{{md.upDown}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```